# How to delete all HTML tags appearing in a variable in BASH?

Tags: html, bash, variables, awk, sed

I have a BASH variable, containing some HTML tags, e.g.:

```
word="<b><div class="light">apple</div></b><i>This is some text.</i>"
```

I need to delete all of the HTML, essentially everything between each pair of `<` and `>`, leaving only the content, e.g., the result would be:

```
appleThis is some text.
```

I tried many possible solutions:

```
word="$(sed 's#<.*>##g' <<< $word)"
word="$(awk '/<html>/{f=1;next} !f; /<\/html>/{f=0}' <<< $word)"
```

Oddly, this seems to delete all of the text.

- Note, it is possible that sometimes an HTML tag has no closing tag, but all tags, should be removed, regardless of whether a pair is found.

How can I delete all HTML tags from a BASH variable?

Comment: Use a XML parser.  `xmlstarlet`, maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment, it'd be better to use a XML parser.

Should you insist upon using a regex, you could make use of negated character class in `sed`:

```
sed 's/<[^>]*>//g' <<< "$word"
```

Answer (score 2):

As everyone has stated, don't use regular expressions. It will break sooner or later. Use a language that provides some assistance in stripping HTML. Perl for example has a CPAN module called [HTML::Strip](http://search.cpan.org/dist/HTML-Strip/Strip.pm). Using that, you can do:

```
$ word="<b><div class="light">apple</div></b><i>This is some text.</i>"
$ perl -MHTML::Strip -lpe '{$hs = HTML::Strip->new(); $_ = $hs->parse($_)}' <<< "$word"
apple This is some text.
```

Answer (score 1):

in [USEFUL ONE-LINE SCRIPTS FOR SED](http://sed.sourceforge.net/sed1line.txt), there are exist samples for your request.

```
sed -e :a -e 's/<[^>]*>//g;/</N;//ba' <<< $word
```

Answer (score 1):

Repetition (like `*`) defaults to be greedy in regular expressions. Therefore `<.*>` will match everything from the first `<` until the last `>`. In your case it will simply match the whole string and therefore delete everything.

You need to use either `<[^>]*>` to explicitly not match `<` or use `<.*?>` to enable the non-greedy version of a repetition.

BTW: Having HTML in a bash variable sounds really strange. Maybe there is a much easier way to accomplish whatever you want to do without a bash variable in between.